# Minifig rotatable legs on a stick - what is this?

Tags: minifigures, part-identification

[image: Minifig rotatable legs on a stick]

What kind of piece is this? Emboss says "(c)2003 The LEGO Group" and there is a **4303** number below. I browsed Peeron a little but didn't find anything similar.

There are two red handles, one rotates minifig legs back and forth, second one make it straight.

*EDIT: fixed part number, it is 4303, small chance for 1303 with overburned 1*

Comment: For me the same piece reads 6423, very weird lol. It looks exactly like yours.

Answer (score 25):

The part in question shows up as a ["Minifig Gravity Stunt Handle" (part number **x817**) on Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/x817) and a ["Turntable Spinning with Sports Trick Handle" (item number **bb128**) on BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb128). Looks like it appears in two sets:

- [Snowboard Super Pipe](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=3585-1):

  [image]
- [Skateboard Vert Park Challenge](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=3537-1):

  [image]

Comment: Thanks! It was in fact sport-related. I've personally never seen this sets, neither live nor in catalog.

Comment: More from [Gravity Games series](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Sports&subtheme=Gravity%20Games)

Comment: @tomash: Are you saying you found this part in a different set? I haven't yet been able to find any other set besides the two above that had a part like this.

Comment: I remember both these sets, but I think I'd rather forget them.

Comment: @gnovice - I found this part in bag of second-hand bricks, so there was no clue about origin set

Answer (score 9):

It's a ["Turntable Spinning with Sports Trick Handle 2 x 24 x 4 1/3"](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=bb128). I found that on BrickLink via [browsing by colour](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&colorPart=2&v=3), since there aren't a lot of tan parts and most of the categories are obviously not applicable (it's not a tile, for example). That page also lists the sets it came in (two of them), but none of the pictures show that part. But once you have the set number an image search turns up shots like these:

[image: weird Lego part in use 1]

[image: weird Lego part in use 1]

I looked it up because I've actually seen one of these in a pile of Lego and wondered what it was, and how it was originally used. It seems like a peculiarly useless part, and I couldn't come up with a use for it that made any sense.

Comment: It's for actively playing with the set, after it's built. It works best if you know how to make that particular board-on-snow scraping/swooshing sound.